# No puedo instalar packages con npm (npm ERR network proxy or have bad network settings)

Tags: nodejs, xampp, npm, nginx, proxy

No puedo instalar paquetes desde que instale nginx y xampp, ya los desinstale, tambien intente reinstalar node y npm, y los siguientes comandos:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.com
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
set PROXY null (algo asi)
set HTTPS-PROXY null (algo asi)
```

sigo sin poder instalar nada

Error que me tira siempre:

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! syscall connect npm ERR! errno
> ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network request to
> http://registry.npmjs.org/@vercel%2fanalytics failed, reason: connect
> ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1323:80 npm ERR! network This is a problem
> related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you
> are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm
> ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm
> ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\matia\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-24T19_57_30_446Z-debug-0.log

Comment: prueba alguna de estas soluciones: [SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

Comment: Hice lo mismo con PowerShell esta vez y parece funcionar, pude instalar, pero igual me tira una warning de que registry esta deprecado:

Comment: npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently 
using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/

Comment: Igual muchas gracias infinit3loop !!

Comment: utiliza una vpn o simplemente configura el proxy local, npm tiene un archivo para eso que se encuentra en el directorio de su usuario donde tiene instalado el sistema operativo